# Countdown Timer in a strip status label c#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, countdown

My program has a parameter that starts up the winform and waits **x** number of seconds before it runs a function. Currently I am using Thread Sleep for **x** seconds and then the function runs. how can I add a timer in the strip status label?

so that it says: `x Seconds Remaining...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of blocking thread execution, simply call your method when required timeout passes. Place new `Timer` to your form, and set it's Interval to `1000`. Then subscribe to timer's `Tick` event and calculate elapsed time in event handler:

```
private int secondsToWait = 42;
private DateTime startTime;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start(); // start timer (you can do it on form load, if you need)
    startTime = DateTime.Now; // and remember start time
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int elapsedSeconds = (int)(DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
    int remainingSeconds = secondsToWait - elapsedSeconds;

    if (remainingSeconds <= 0)
    {
        // run your function
        timer.Stop();
    }

    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = 
        String.Format("{0} seconds remaining...", remainingSeconds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Timer`:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        t = new Timer {Interval = 1000};
        t.Tick += Tick;
        //try counting down the time
        CountDown(100);
    }
    DateTime start;
    Timer t;  
    long s;
    public void CountDown(long seconds){
       start = DateTime.Now;
       s = seconds;
       t.Start();
    }
    private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
       long remainingSeconds = s - (DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds;
       if(remainingSeconds <= 0) {
         t.Stop(); 
         toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Done!";
         return;
       }
       toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = string.Format("{0} seconds remaining...", remainingSeconds);
    }
}
```